# Force date and day name to appear in X axis

Tags: rrdtool

I need to make both the day name and the date appear in the X-axis. So far, rrdtool seems to decide whether to put the date (only the day of the month though, eg: 17, 18 etc) or the day name depending on the size of the rendered image. As seen in the below images.

How do I make rrdtool do something like this:

```
First line:  Tuesday
Second line: 14/07/2015
```

Or even:

```
First line:  Tuesday  
Second line: 14th July 2015
```

For each day within the week?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the format of the x-axis labels using the `--x-grid` option.

The parameters specify all the properties of the x-grid including the labels and their positioning. You can not have a multi-line label, but you can use full strftime formatting to specify a label of your choice.

Normally rrdtool will pick something 'sensible' automatically but you can specify your own rule if you want:

`[-x|--x-grid GTM:GST:MTM:MST:LTM:LST:LPR:LFM]`

The grid is defined by specifying a certain amount of time in the `?TM` positions. You can choose from `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `HOUR`, `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH` or `YEAR`. Then you define how many of these should pass between each line or label. This pair `(?TM:?ST)` needs to be specified for the base grid `(G??)`, the major grid `(M??)` and the labels `(L??)`. For the labels you also must define a precision in `LPR` and a strftime format string in `LFM`. `LPR` defines where each label will be placed. If it is zero, the label will be placed right under the corresponding line (useful for hours, dates etcetera). If you specify a number of seconds here the label is centered on this interval (useful for Monday, January etcetera).

`--x-grid MINUTE:10:HOUR:1:HOUR:4:0:%X`

This places grid lines every 10 minutes, major grid lines every hour, and labels every 4 hours. The labels are placed under the major grid lines as they specify exactly that time.

`--x-grid HOUR:8:DAY:1:DAY:1:86400:%A`

This places grid lines every 8 hours, major grid lines and labels each day. The labels are placed exactly between two major grid lines as they specify the complete day and not just midnight.

A strftime format to show weekday and date would be `%a %D`

Also note that with rrdtool 1.5.x the automatic labeling code has been re-done ... and produces more sensible results.

Comment: What Tobi said, in addition to that the `LFM` uses the same formate as the `date` command in linux. Run `man date` to get a list of options

Comment: @Nakilon, nope, I meant `man date`, but strftime works too

Comment: ok, maybe man was different on linux and macos when I tried before leaving the comment